# Python: Are numpy arrays linked when one array is transposed?

Tags: python, arrays, pointers, numpy

Currently I am working on a python script which extracts measurement data from a text file. I am working with iPython Notebook and Python 2.7

Now I experienced some odd behaviour when working with numpy arrays. I have no explanation for this.

```
myArray = numpy.zeros((4,3))
myArrayTransposed = myArray.transpose()

for i in range(0,4):
    for j in range(0,3):
        myArray[i][j] = i+j

print myArray
print myArrayTransposed
```

leads to:

```
[[ 0.  1.  2.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 2.  3.  4.]
 [ 3.  4.  5.]]
 [[ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.  4.]
 [ 2.  3.  4.  5.]]
```

So without working on the transposed array, values are updated in this array.

How is this possible?

Comment: transpose does not create a copy. It just changes the order the same data is read into. Would be strange if the numpy docs did not mention this

Comment: They indeed mention it [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html). The return valur is a "View" to the original array

Comment: `myArray.T.copy()` if you want a true copy. `.T` is shorthand for `.transpose()`

Answer (score 4):

From http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html:

> Different ndarrays can share the same data, so that changes made in one ndarray may be visible in another. That is, an ndarray can be a “view” to another ndarray, and the data it is referring to is taken care of by the “base” ndarray. ndarrays can also be views to memory owned by Python strings or objects implementing the buffer or array interfaces.

When you do a transpose(), this returns a "view" to the original ndarray. It points to the same memory buffer, but it has a different indexing scheme:

> A segment of memory is inherently 1-dimensional, and there are many different schemes for arranging the items of an N-dimensional array in a 1-dimensional block. Numpy is flexible, and ndarray objects can accommodate any strided indexing scheme.

To create an independent ndarray, you can use numpy.array() operator:

```
myArrayTransposed = myArray.transpose().copy()
```

Comment: Hello and thanks to all who have answered my questions. You gave me valuable hints. Have a nice day!

Comment: Maybe the `numpy.copy` function would be more explicit to achieve what the OP wants: `myArrayTransposed = myArray.transpose().copy()`

Comment: Yes. I agree. Fixed it :-)